# Rewrite PHP Pages to HTML without duplication

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have been searching and testing for hours but cannot find a solution.

This is my code:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

# Specify search friendly URLs
RewriteRule ^first-services\.html$ /subfolder/services.php?sid=2 [L]
```

I want to redirect this page from PHP form to HTML.

Thanks

Comment: Did you make sure you have enabled rewrite engine?

Comment: If you use apache check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/869092/how-to-enable-mod-rewrite-for-apache-2-2

Comment: Mr. Keloo my code is working, but the problem there is duplicate content, Because PHP page working and HTML also working, but I need to redirect  PHP page to HTML.